# Outlook cmd select folder from non default email account

Tags: windows, command-line, outlook, command

Let's say I've `xxx@outlook.com` and `yyy@outlook.com` both are configured in my outlook where `xxx@outlook.com` is my default account.

The following command opens a new window in outlook and navigates to the zz folder in `Drafts` in `xxx@outlook.com`.

```
Outlook.exe /select outlook:Drafts/zz
```

I wonder is there a way to perform this same operation on the `yyy@outlook.com` (Anything other than the default account). I tried the following  but it didn't help.

```
Outlook.exe /select outlook:yyy@outlook.com:Drafts/zz
```

I want to select a folder from a non default account through command line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer. Its so simple. I don't know how I missed this.

```
Outlook.exe /select "outlook:\\yyy@outlook.com\Drafts\zz"
```

It may be helpful for others.